# Using VSCode, unable to import pytest or setuptools in venv

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, pytest, pylance

I have created and activated a virtual environment, and installed pytest using pip

```
python3 -m venv venv
source venv/bin/activate
pip install -U pytest
```

The following lines are creating import errors:

`import pytest`

`import setuptools`

It's a tiny project, there are 2 files: calculator.py and test_calculator.py.

Pytest runs the unit tests when I use the `pytest` command, but I am not able to import pytest into the test file, and I don't have access to any of Pytest's features, e.g. @pytest.fixture, in the test file.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't using the python interpreter for the virtual environment. In the bottom right corner of Visual Studio Code, is the name of the Python interpreter that is being used. Click on it, and select the Python interpreter that is associated with the virtual environment.